# SpecificationError: Function names must be unique if there is no new column names assigned

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to create a new column in the `clin` dataframe based on the following conditions:

- 1 if vals>=2*365 or is NAN
- otherwise 0

I then assign the new column name as `SURV`.

```
import numpy as np

vals = clin['days_to_death'].astype(np.float32)

# non-LTS is 0, LTS is 1
surv = [1  if ( v>=2*365 or np.isnan(v) ) else 0 for v in vals ]
clin['SURV'] = clin.apply(surv, axis=1)
```

Traceback:

```
SpecificationError: Function names must be unique if there is no new column names assigned
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SpecificationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-603dee8413ce> in <module>
      5 # non-LTS is 0, LTS is 1
      6 surv = [1  if ( v>=2*365 or np.isnan(v) ) else 0 for v in vals ]
----> 7 clin['SURV'] = clin.apply(surv, axis=1)

/shared-libs/python3.7/py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

/shared-libs/python3.7/py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    146             # multiple values for keyword argument "axis"
    147             return self.obj.aggregate(  # type: ignore[misc]
--> 148                 self.f, axis=self.axis, *self.args, **self.kwds
    149             )
    150 

/shared-libs/python3.7/py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in aggregate(self, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   7572         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   7573 
-> 7574         relabeling, func, columns, order = reconstruct_func(func, **kwargs)
   7575 
   7576         result = None

/shared-libs/python3.7/py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/aggregation.py in reconstruct_func(func, **kwargs)
     93             # there is no reassigned name
     94             raise SpecificationError(
---> 95                 "Function names must be unique if there is no new column names "
     96                 "assigned"
     97             )

SpecificationError: Function names must be unique if there is no new column names assigned
```

`clin`

```
clin = pd.DataFrame([[1, '466', '47', 0, '90'],
   [1, '357', '54', 1, '80'],
   [1, '108', '72', 1, '60'],
   [1, '254', '51', 0, '80'],
   [1, '138', '78', 1, '80'],
   [0, nan, '67', 0, '60']], columns=['vital_status', 'days_to_death', 'age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis',
   'gender', 'karnofsky_performance_score'], index=['TCGA-06-1806', 'TCGA-06-5408', 'TCGA-06-5410', 'TCGA-06-5411',
   'TCGA-06-5412', 'TCGA-06-5413'])
```

Expected output:

|  | vital_status | days_to_death | age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis | gender | karnofsky_performance_score | SURV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCGA-06-1806 | 1 | 466 | 47 | 0 | 90 | 0 |
| TCGA-06-5408 | 1 | 357 | 54 | 1 | 80 | 0 |
| TCGA-06-5410 | 1 | 108 | 72 | 1 | 60 | 0 |
| TCGA-06-5411 | 1 | 254 | 51 | 0 | 80 | 0 |
| TCGA-06-5412 | 1 | 138 | 78 | 1 | 80 | 0 |
| TCGA-06-5413 | 0 | nan | 67 | 0 | 60 | 1 |

Comment: Is there a reason your dataframe as values stored as strings rather than integers?

Comment: you give `apply` a list.  Shouldn't that be a function? Read the docs.  Also that list name looks a lot like a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new column of all 0's and then update the column with your desired parameters.

```
clin['SURV'] = 0
clin.loc[pd.to_numeric(clin.days_to_death).ge(2*365) | clin.days_to_death.isna(), 'SURV'] = 1
print(clin)
```

Output:

```
              vital_status days_to_death age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis  gender karnofsky_performance_score  SURV
TCGA-06-1806             1           466                                  47       0                          90     0
TCGA-06-5408             1           357                                  54       1                          80     0
TCGA-06-5410             1           108                                  72       1                          60     0
TCGA-06-5411             1           254                                  51       0                          80     0
TCGA-06-5412             1           138                                  78       1                          80     0
TCGA-06-5413             0           NaN                                  67       0                          60     1
```